# Encoding problem in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I am trying to save a screen name in column on SQL Server 2008 without any special and international characters so that i can use that column in URL.

Can you guys please suggest some technique how to save this name in column with out any special or international characters.

Basic purpose of this is to use this column in URL.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please explain more of the intent:  is there some problem with "screen name" containing extended characters?  If so, why not just remove them on entry, or prohibit their use by an appropriate edit control?

Comment: Basic intent is if i am saving special and international characters in column.If i use that column for URL.i am getting problems like bad request because i cant use such characters in URL.So that i want ignore those characters and i want to save screen name in separate column not in screen name column.

Comment: Are you talking about extended codepage stuff or only about escaping the special characters in url encoding? If the second then you can just use nested REPLACE functions obeying these rules: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: yeah some thing like this,can i get technique with removing all special and international for URL So i doesn't go to bad request.

Comment: Sounds liek you should rather read HOW TO ENCODE THOSE SPECIAL CHARS IN A URL. It is not like HTTP does not have a standard for this.

Answer (score 2):

You should urlencode the strings you store in the database instead of "removing" the invalid characters.

```
string url = "http://xyz.com/" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myFieldContent);
```

This will replace the "special" characters with their corresponding percent encoding. See [The RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) for more information.